# Bash, converting byte to ascii hex without hexdump or xxd

Tags: bash

I want to convert a binary file to an ASCII representation of hex.  This is actually due to a weird portability issue in sharing my academic work.  The motivation is that it is easier to have a file represented in hex as large values printed in ASCII.  I have the unique situation where I have BASH, but might not have xxd or hexdump.  I was trying to make a bash script that takes a file, reads a byte, and then outputs a value as ASCII hex.  I thought printf would be the way to go, but if the file has binary 0x30, it prints out ASCII "0".

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUTFILE=$1
while IFS= read -r -n1 filechar
do
  printf  "%02X" "$filechar"
done < "$INPUTFILE"
printf "\n"
```

I am unclear why "%02X" is not returning "30" for the ascii value of "0".   Again, the real crux of the problem is that I am trying to ONLY use Bash because I cannot guarantee that anyone has anything but Bash.  To make matters worse, I'm trying for Bash 3.x.   Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: The reason it's printing `0` is because that's the value it's reading.  You are reading each character from the file, so the `filechar` value has the value of 0.  The `printf` binary doesn't interpret the characters you pass to it as numbers.  Can you not use `od -tx $INPUTFILE`?  That should be POSIX-friendly.

Comment: @eddiem Maybe.  Image a system that is so secure that it's impossible to use.  This is why I am trying to do everything in bash, as that works.  It's just a pipe nightmare.  "od" is a good choice as it's been around forever.  I didn't know about od until you mentioned it. I'll ask the admins if I can be sure everyone can run that.

Comment: You will have trouble with some character values: character 0 (ASCII NULL) cannot be represented in a shell variable or passed as an argument, and characters above 127 (hex 7f) may be problematic depending on your locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way, albeit terrible by loading the file into a string.

```
#!/bin/sh
FILESTRING=$(<$1)
for ((i=0;i<${#FILESTRING};i++));
do 
   printf %02X \'${FILESTRING:$i:1};
done
```

In this method, I need no external executable so I do not have to worry about anything outside of Bash.  Thanks to everyone who commented.

Answer (score 1):

If the character is preceded with an apostrophe, the ASCII value of the character is used.

```
printf  "%02X" "'$filechar"
```

I don't believe this will work for non-ASCII (> 127) characters, however.